# Why is the FileAttributes value for a file which does not exist -1?

Tags: c#, fileinfo, system.io.fileinfo

Consider the below code -

```
 FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("C:\\doesNotExist.txt");
 Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.Attributes);
 Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly));
```

As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx), the default underlying type for an enumeration is *int* and an *int* with a value of -1 is basically all 1s in binary. Since, FileAttributes allows a bitwise combination of its member values ([as stated here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes(v=vs.110).aspx)), why is the default value for FileAttributes -1 as it would mean that a file which does not exist possesses all possible FileAttributes (the above code prints *True* for the third line)

Comment: Backwards compatibility.  Use File.GetAttributes() instead, it throws.

Answer (score 1):

This is only conjecture and the source is confusing, but it looks like it may be so the code can tell the difference between data which has not been initialized - i.e. an int defaulting to zero - and data which has been initialized, but has no value, like the file attributes on a non-existent file.

From the [source code for File.FillAttributeInfo](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,1354)

```
// Returns 0 on success, otherwise a Win32 error code.  Note that
// classes should use -1 as the uninitialized state for dataInitialized.
```

And [then](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,1443) if the file is not found:

```
if (!returnErrorOnNotFound) {
    // Return default value for backward compbatibility
    dataInitialised = 0;
    data.fileAttributes = -1;
}
```

It seems reasonable to expect callers to check that the FileInfo's `Exists` property is true before accessing the attributes.